# Why is up vector orthogonal to left vector?

Tags: quantum-information

My book defines qubit basis vectors based on photon polarization example. It says that QC prefers orthonormal basis, e.g. $|0⟩=|\uparrow⟩$ and $|1⟩=|\rightarrow⟩$. How do they know/prove that $|\uparrow⟩$ and $|\rightarrow⟩$ are orthogonal? This is probably a question for information technology but I guess you know better than stackoverflow.

Comment: Does that say $g \mid \uparrow \rangle$ for a unitary g applied? If so what is g?

Comment: @AHusain g is from e.g. That is English language uses Latin borrowings. Thanks for spotting that. I have added a period there.

Answer (score 0):

It is choosing an orthonormal basis. Without loss of generality, you may treat it as

$$
\mid \uparrow \rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\\
\mid \rightarrow \rangle = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$

but you should call it $\mid \downarrow \rangle$ instead of $\mid \rightarrow \rangle$. This is because you're differentiating them as eigenstates of $\sigma^z$. You could do $\sigma^x$ too but then you could do $\mid \leftarrow \rangle$ and $\mid \rightarrow \rangle$ instead. Similarly with any other choice, but just stick with $\sigma^z$ because it loses no generality while sticking with usual conventions.

So the inner product is defined as

$$
\langle a \uparrow + b \downarrow \mid c \uparrow + d \downarrow \rangle = \bar{a}c +\bar{b}d
$$

Edit: Ah polarization. So they are orthonormal because look at the projectors. The $\mid \uparrow \rangle \langle \uparrow \mid$ projector is implemented by a vertical polarizer. Similarly $\mid \rightarrow \rangle \langle \rightarrow \mid$. Take the product

$$
\mid \uparrow \rangle \langle \uparrow \mid \mid \rightarrow \rangle \langle \rightarrow \mid = ( \langle \uparrow \mid \rightarrow \rangle ) \mid \uparrow \rangle \langle \rightarrow \mid = 0
$$

This is because after a polarizing in the different directions no light gets through. So that inner product is 0. That is the physics of why the inner product is defined as above.

Comment: My book says that up-down is used for spins instead of polarization. Secondly, I do not see any proof of orthonormality. How can matrix representation, that you choose arbitrarily, be a proof? I do not see any proof in saying that I can stick to any axis either.